# Getting dm-event.socket error during booting of the machine

Tags: boot, systemd

Getting following systemd error while booting up. The operation system is ubuntu 20.04LTS. This error could be preexisting (I upgraded the os 3 days back):

```
 systemd[1]: dm-event.socket: Socket service dm-event.service not loaded, refusing.
 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress >
 systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Job lvm2-monitor.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
 systemd[1]: lvm2-lvmpolld.socket: Socket service lvm2-lvmpolld.service not loaded, refusing.
 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
```

What is the impact of this error? How can we fix this error?